# Combining two Beta disributions

Tags: probability-distributions

I want to combine two beta distributions to find the the posterior distribution as the precision-weighted combination of the prior and the likelihood distributions. As the prior and likelihood I have two beta distributions. How do i combine them? Want to know about all the theoretical techniques available. Is there any article which may help me in the analysis. Even guiding me with a weblink to any article would also help!

Regards,
Bik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear exactly what you are asking for.

If your prior distribution is $B(\alpha,\beta)$ then the prior density is proportional to $x^{\alpha-1} (1-x)^{\beta-1}$.

Your likelihood function is perhaps proportional to $x^{\gamma} (1-x)^{\delta}$.

So you multiply these together and your posterior density is proportional to $x^{\alpha+\gamma-1} (1-x)^{\beta+\delta-1}$ which means your posterior distribution is $B(\alpha+\gamma,\beta+\delta)$.

Comment: Hello @Henry!
Firstly, thanks a ton for helping me.

Let me give more explanation on my query:
I am trying to combine two beta distributions _B1_ (_a1_,_b1_) and _B2_ (_a2_,_b2_) using spreadsheet to get another alpha (_a3_) and beta (_b3_) for a combined beta distribution. 
Using this technique I intend to combine expert judgement and data to recalibrate my model. One of the option which I have is to take a weighted average of the paramaters (a1,b1,a2 and b2) to arrive at a3 and b3. Just wanted to inquire if there are other techniques available. Looking forwark for your response...

Comment: What is supposed to be distributed with a Beta distribution? The parameter of another distribution?

Comment: Yes... you are right...